# gitlab-runner exec with dind (docker in docker) minimal working example

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
image: docker:18

varibales:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: "overlay2"
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

test:
  services:
    - "docker:18-dind"
  script:
    - docker info
```

I run it with:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged --docker-pull-policy if-not-present --docker-tlsverify=false test
```

and it works.

---

But I want to use current docker version. So I [read this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor).

```yaml
image: docker:19

varibales:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: "overlay2"
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

test:
  services:
    - "docker:19-dind"
  script:
    - docker info
```

I run it with the same as above:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged --docker-pull-policy if-not-present --docker-tlsverify=false test
```

unfortunately this ends with error:

> ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

I have saw [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4501) and many others. But I couldn't find a minimal working example that works with `gitlab-runner exec docker` on every unix system with `docker:19` and `docker:19-dind`

EDIT:
gitlab-runner  --version(from Manajaro repo):

```
Version:      13.0.0
Git revision: HEAD
Git branch:   HEAD
GO version:   go1.14.4
Built:        unknown
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```